# Why does the github repo of CPython says it contains python code?

Tags: python, interpreter

Does the CPython Interpreter itself contain Python code? I could not find any answers on the internet.

When you go to the [Github Repo](https://github.com/python/cpython), you see that it contains about 65% python code. But I could not really find any in what looked like interpreter/compiler code, that was all C.

Is there any?

Comment: Almost the entire `Lib` is written in Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib

Comment: Most of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) is written in python.  Check the `Lib` directory.

Comment: Which came first, the python or the egg?

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the word "Python" in the language statistics and you will get a list of all files containing Python code: https://github.com/python/cpython/search?l=python